# XML parsing using DOM to get first level child nodes

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have written this code for parsing an XML file. I want to print the o/p in form of tree (root,children,grand children). But its printing every nodes (child nodes and grandchildren nodes) as child node of the root node.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

public class Parsing{

public static void traverse (Node n) throws Exception
{
    // Extract node info:
    String TextNode = "TextNode";
    String AttrVal = "";
    int ind;
    String nodename = n.getNodeName();
    String valueStr = n.getNodeValue();
    Boolean bo = n.hasAttributes();

    String xml1 = "";

    if (valueStr != null)
        valueStr = valueStr.trim();
    // Print and continue traversing.
    if(!nodename.equals("#text"))
    {
        if(bo==true)
        {
            NamedNodeMap nm1 = n.getAttributes();
            if(valueStr==null)//If node has no value
                System.out.println(""+ n.getNodeName());
            else 
                System.out.println( "" + n.getNodeName() + "  Value = " + valueStr + " " );
                System.out.println( "\t\tAttributes: ");
            for(int i = 0 ; i<nm1.getLength() ; i++)
            {
                Attr attribute = (Attr)nm1.item(i);     
                AttrVal = attribute.getValue();
                ind = AttrVal.indexOf(":");
                ind++;
                System.out.println( "\t\t\t"  + attribute.getName()+" = "+attribute.getValue());


         }

        {
            if(valueStr==null)
                System.out.println (" " + n.getNodeName() );
            else
                System.out.println (" " + n.getNodeName() + "  Value = " + valueStr + " ");
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        if(!valueStr.equals(""))
        System.out.println (" "  + TextNode + "  Value = " + valueStr + " ");
    }    

    // Now traverse the rest of the tree in depth-first order.
    if (n.hasChildNodes()) 
    {
      // Get the children in a list.
      NodeList nl = n.getChildNodes();
      // No. of children
      int size = nl.getLength();
      for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
      // Recursively traverse each of the children.
      traverse (nl.item(i));
    }
}

public static void parse (String a1){
try 
    {
            System.out.println("Name"   +  a1);
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(a1));
            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());            
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            System.out.println("ROOT ELEMENT IS" + root);
            traverse (root);
    }

catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        t.printStackTrace ();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter int depth to method traverse:

```
public static void traverse (Node n, int depth) throws Exception
```

and increment the value every time you traverse the child nodes for a node:

```
traverse(root,0);
```

and

```
traverse(nl.item(i),depth+1);
```

Finally, modify your print statements to indent based of the value of depth.

Comment: We have included below snippet along wit your parameter(depth) but still I m getting every node as child node of root node(no grand children)

Comment: if(n.hasChildNodes())
    {
     NodeList n1 = n.getChildNodes();

       for (isd = 0; isd < n1.getLength(); isd++) 
       {
        System.out.println("\t\tChildren:" + n1.item(isd));
       }

    }

Comment: This is my sample xml file with o/p I m getting <System_Configuration>
  <Description></Description>
  <Audit>
    <Application><Application/>
  </Audit>
  <Software>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Value>12343</Value>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Software>
  <Software>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Value>51234</Value>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Software>
  </System_Configuration>

System_Configuration//root node
we get 
Description
Audit
Application
Software
Properties
Property
Value
and so on
i.e., every nodes are displayed as the children node